# Errorbar plot with multiple y-axes produces ValueError

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create an errorbar plot with multiple y-axes using as a template the plot with multiple axes from [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html). If I alter only this line of the template:

`p1, = host.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], "b-", label="Density")`

to this:

`p1, = host.errorbar([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], yerr=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], fmt='b-', label="Density")`

I get as output:

1. The errorbar plot with multiple y-axes but only the p1 data are displayed.
2. A 'ValueError: too many values to unpack'.

Could someone help explain why this is the case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errorbar` and `plot` return different things. `plot` returns a list of lines, but in this case, the code is assuming that there's only a single line returned, and so `p1,` and so on takes that out of the list.

`errorbar` instead returns a Container object, and the container contains multiple lines. You can't use `p1,` for `errorbar`'s return. You'll need instead to deal with it differently.

`p1` is used for two different purposes later in the code: to set the color, and to set the label. As it turns out, `get_label` is a method of the Container. `get_color` isn't, but it is a method of children of the container, and the should be the same color. So change the code to just assign the container to `p1`, and use the color of one of its children. For example:

```
p1 = host.errorbar([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], yerr=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
                   fmt='b-', label="Density")
```

Then:

```
host.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_children()[0].get_color())
```

and

```
host.tick_params(axis='y', colors=p1.get_children()[0].get_color(), **tkw)
```

The legend-setting code doesn't need to be changed at all.